# restore wallet using hd seed before 0.17.0

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet

Hd wallets are supported from v0.13.0.

Currently it is easy to save hd seed and restore a wallet from it (due to changes in v0.17.0 and v0.18.0):

1. dumpwallet (read hdseed from it)
2. createwallet (blank wallet)
3. sethdseed (set hdseed on a blank wallet)

**How to do this using v0.16.3?**

Problems I encountered:

- I cannot find **hdseed** in dumped wallet file, so I don't know hd seed to backup
- creating new wallets is done by starting bitcoind and passing -wallet option, but I don't see a way to specify hd seed when creating a new wallet

Is that even possible without upgrading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot find hdseed in dumped wallet file, so I don't know hd seed to backup

It used to be called `hdmaster` rather than `hdseed`.

> - creating new wallets is done by starting bitcoind and passing -wallet option, but I don't see a way to specify hd seed when creating a new wallet
>
> Is that even possible without upgrading?

No. `sethdseed` was added in 0.17. Before that, there was no way to restore a seed to a new wallet in Core.